# Unix Touch in Matlab to create a file?

Tags: file, matlab, unix

This is probably very easy thing but `help touch` does not return anything, I am trying to create a file. I could find `mkdir` in Matlab but not `touch` so how to create a file in Matlab ie the unix-style command `$ touch newFile`?

Comment: on Unix-like machines, call the system's `touch` command. On [Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command), you could obtain a native Win32 port of it from [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `system('touch newfile')`?

Answer (score 0):

try this then hopefully help !
    http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/creating-opening-changing-and-deleting-files-and-folders.html